# Check if file contains string1 AND NOT string2

Tags: bash, grep, gnu-coreutils

I've got a program (`prog`) that takes a lot of time to produce its output.

I need to check if the output contains *string1* **and not** *string2*.

Right now I do the following.  It invokes `prog` 2 times.

```
if   prog | grep -q 'some string' &&
   ! prog | grep -q 'another string'; then
    echo 'OK'
else
    echo 'Not OK'
fi
```

Is there are way to do this with only 1 invocation of `prog`?

Any solution involving *awk* or *sed* will do as well.

**UPDATE**

What I was hoping for was a one liner—that my mind cannot see—to do the trick, having GNU coreutils at my disposal.

Comment: 1) use a temp file? 2) process line-by-line.

Comment: That would do. Just feeling I am missing something, it shouldn't be that hard :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with `grep` without executing `prog` twice, or better, saving it's output into a temporary file.

I would recommend to use `awk`:

```
awk '/string1/{a=1}/string2/{b=1}END{exit !a && b}'
```

You can use it in the shell script like:

```
if prog | awk '/string1/{a=1}/string2/{b=1}END{exit !a && b}' ; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

Note: `awk` treats `0` as false and `1` as true. The shell treats `0` as true and `1` as false. To reflect that we return `!a && b` instead of the `a && !b`, which might look more reasonable in the first place.

Comment: Especially if the condition gets more complicated `awk` comes in handy.

Comment: It's simpler to think of the shell as dealing with success and failure, not boolean values. 0 indicates success, non-zero indicates failure.

Comment: In my case I had to do `exit a && b`. Or inspired by @chepner: `awk 'BEGIN{a=1;b=0}/string1/{a=0}/string2/{b=1}END{exit a + b}'`.

Answer (score 2):

With sed, to output line that meet the requirements :

```
prog | sed -n ':a;$!N;s/\n//;ta;/string1/{/string2/!p}'
```

**Update :**

To test the sed command (GNU sed) :

```
prog | sed -n ':a;$!N;s/\n//;ta;/string1/{/string2/!{q};/string2/{q 1}}' && echo "ok" || echo "nok"
```

Comment: This operates just on a single line, not on the whole output.

Comment: @hek2mgl Updated for multiline output.

Comment: Having that you have `string1` in `$1` and string2 in `$2`, this will do as well: `sed -n "/$1/H;/$2/H;\${x;/$1/{/$2/q1}}" file` (with GNU sed) I'm using the hold buffer for matching lines only instead of buffering the whole file.

Comment: Actually I don't need to use the hold buffer. This should do as well: `sed -n "/$1/!d;/$2/!d;N;\${/$1/{/$2/q1}}" file`

Comment: @hek2mgl I tried `sed -n "/foo/!d;/bar/!d;N;\${/foo/{/bar/q1}}" <<< "foo, bar"; echo $?`, it returns `0`. Something I missed ?

Comment: Uh. The `!` needs to get escape. That's because I'm using double chars. I thought `$1` would be simpler than `string1`. But as you see, it brings nothing more than trouble! Damn! :) `foo`, `bar` would have been enough...

Comment: There's a stray `file` in your update I think. If removed it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the problem by using grep command :

```
prog | grep -E 'string1|string2' | tr -d "\n" | grep  -v string2 | grep string1 && echo "OK" || echo "NOT OK"
```

Comment: Creative use of `tr`. Thanks.